# Authorization via Metamask

Tags: metamask, signature

On my site I do not want to use email/pass authorization, but insteand I'd like to use Metamask `sign` functionality (it is impossible to work with site without Metamask or browser with `web3`).

I suppose to implement something like this:

- client generates any random string/pin code.
- on "login" click sign it and sends alongside with pincode to server (I know that I can use any static phrase and it doesn't increases overall security).
- there signature checked and public key/address derived.
- if user with such public key/address found - generate standard JWT and use it with all following REST requests.

I am wondering is it safe enough or I missed something important?

Comment: looking for similar I found this, not sure if quite what you need but helpful: https://hackernoon.com/never-use-passwords-again-with-ethereum-and-metamask-b61c7e409f0d

Comment: @majick thanks, I already implemented it and cannot see any security cons in this approach.

Comment: certainly looks like the way to go, any tips or code you can share? this is totally not my area of expertise (yet.)

Answer (score 1):

This has been done multiple times, but this is one that really goes into details on it

https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial